# ¿Cómo cambiar texto a mayúsculas en HTML con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

He utilizado estos tres comandos (CSS, JavaScript, Bootstrap)

```
<input style="text-transform:uppercase" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" class="uppercase"></input>
```

El detalle es que en la base de datos, tengo una vista donde va a recoger los datos y el nombre está en mayúsculas, pero al hacerle `uppercase` de cualquiera de las 3 formas anteriores no lo encuentra, solamente lo encuentra si activo las mayúsculas desde el teclado.

que podría hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Hola, tal vez deberías subir el código de la vista que recoge los datos también para entender mejor el problema.

Answer (score 1):

El **javascript** en **onkeyup** esta de mas.

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
```

El css, y la clase solo son visuales, pero **this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();** si afectan el valor real.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero tal vez no se entendió bien la pregunta, coloqué todo esto en mi input, pero a pesar de que el texto lo convierte a mayusculas, solo me encuentra el registro en la base de datos si activo las mayúsculas con el teclado.

Comment: @MauEspaña Los comentarios no son lugar para poner código que ocupa varias líneas, si es relevante para hacer más clara tu pregunta incluyendo si se trata de un progreso que has realizado, edita tu pregunta para agregarlo ahí.